# SVN .xcodeproj conflict / transaction issue?

Tags: mac, svn, xcode

I am trying to add my xcodeproj file/folder thingy to my svn repository.

```
medwall-macmini-1:Summer2010 pebble$ svn add CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/pebble.pbxuser
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/pebble.perspectivev3
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/slate.mode1v3
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/slate.mode2v3
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/slate.pbxuser
A         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj/slate.perspectivev3
medwall-macmini-1:Summer2010 pebble$ svn ci -m "Checked In"
Adding         CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File already exists: filesystem '/SVN/Summer2010/db', transaction '21-p', path '/CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj'
```

I then try to Delete it, Check-In, Update it, Add it, and then check it in again but I get the same exact run-around.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the SVN is telling you that `CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj` already exists in your repository.  Your best bet is to rename your `CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj` to something else (`CoreDataTrial.bak.xcodeproj`, for example).  Run an `svn update` to get the latest copy from SVN.  Then take a look at your directory and see if `CoreDataTrial.xcodeproj` is there already.  If it is, you need to delete the original and check in the new one, **or** integrate the two.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't accept this like, months ago.